# Sound is not working after the suspend. ElementaryOs 5.1

Tags: sound, suspend

I was using elementaryos after quite sometime and everything was working fine until today when I loged i after the suspend the sound was not working it was saying "No Output Device Detected" in my Audio Settings and exactly the similar case for the input device.[image]

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost a year late, but I was having this exact issue until now.
What fixed it for me was to run this command after resuming from suspend mode:

> $ pulseaudio -k